# I want to display a byte array type image in html. How Do I?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, byte

All help I could find were for byte64 or using setImageBitmap for android. I want it for javascript.
So I have a particular object:
 byte* img;   //i'd like to print this on an HTML page

Answer (score 0):

You can display base64 data with inline HTML like this:

```
<img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image'                 
   src='data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRBQ...<!-- base64 data -->' />
```